# Compare 2 dates in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am using this to get the date modified of a file:

```
@echo off
FOR %%? IN ("C:\some.exe") DO (
    ECHO Last-Modified Date   : %%~t?
)
```

The above returns something like: Last-Modified Date   : 26/03/2013 14:43.

How can I take the date part from the above and compare it against another file which's name contains a date ie: 23-Sep-13.exe?

I need to be able to perform some code in the batch file if the file that contains the date in its name is later than the file modified version ie install the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: No doubt for international use, this could be retrieved from the registry
SET monthnames=Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
:: get last modified date of target file - your format as specified
:: (I used THIS BATCH FILE)
FOR %%i IN ("%~f0") DO SET target=%%~ti
:: parse the target date
FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=/ " %%i IN ("%target%") DO SET targetf=%%k%%j%%i
::
:: parse name from 'other file'
SET other=23-Sep-13.exe
FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=.- " %%i IN ("%other%") DO SET od=%%i&SET omn=%%j&SET oy=%%k
:: Convert monthname to number
:: @ECHO on
SET om=101
FOR %%i IN (%monthnames%) DO (
IF DEFINED omn IF /i %omn%==%%i (SET omn=) ELSE (SET /a om+=1)
)
:: Build date of 'other file' in same format (YYYYMMDD)
SET otherf=20%oy%%om:~-2%%od%
ECHO is %other% later than %target% ?
ECHO IF %otherf% gtr %targetf% GOTO later
ECHO.
::
:: parse name from 'another other file'
SET other=23-Jan-13.exe
FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=.- " %%i IN ("%other%") DO SET od=%%i&SET omn=%%j&SET oy=%%k
:: Convert monthname to number
SET om=101
FOR %%i IN (%monthnames%) DO (
IF DEFINED omn IF /i %omn%==%%i (SET omn=) ELSE (SET /a om+=1)
)
:: Build date of 'other file' in same format (YYYYMMDD)
SET otherf=20%oy%%om:~-2%%od%
ECHO is %other% later than %target% ?
ECHO IF %otherf% gtr %targetf% GOTO later
ECHO.
```

Code takes date of (this batch) as the target (your `'C:\some.exe'`- change to suit.

test then applied to two different `filename-is-date+ext` format filenames to test.

Can be easily adjusted if comparisons to 20th-Century date is required... :)

Comment: Thanks Peter - this works a treat.

Do you know how to do the same but using the exe's File Version instead of date for the compare ? ie exe file version: 4.5.6.0 = file name: 4050400.exe