# Batch file that aborts action if current date is not between specific dates

Tags: date, batch-file

I need an if else statement that aborts or continues the batch scripts.

if current date is between specified 2 dates it continues to work
if not, batch file aborts

for example i set the dates as 01.01.2019 to 01.03.2019, if the date is 15.02.2019 batch file works if 01.04.2019 it aborts

the closest answers are from here; [In a batch file, how would I check if today's date is after a set date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141220/in-a-batch-file-how-would-i-check-if-todays-date-is-after-a-set-date)

```
@ECHO OFF

SET FirstDate=2015-01-24

REM These indexes assume %DATE% is in format:
REM   Abr MM/DD/YYYY - ex. Sun 01/25/2015
SET TodayYear=%DATE:~10,4%
SET TodayMonth=%DATE:~4,2%
SET TodayDay=%DATE:~7,2%

REM Construct today's date to be in the same format as the FirstDate.
REM Since the format is a comparable string, it will evaluate date orders.
IF %TodayYear%-%TodayMonth%-%TodayDay% GTR %FirstDate% (
    ECHO Today is after the first date.
) ELSE (
    ECHO Today is on or before the first date.
)


and / or

@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS

REM -- 2 digit day
SET "_day=%DATE:~-10,2%" & REM day goes first (dd/mm/yyyy); if not, remove this line
SET "_day=%DATE:~-7,2%" & REM day goes second (mm/dd/yyyy); if not, remove this line
REM -- 2 digit month
SET "_month=%DATE:~-10,2%" & REM month goes first (mm/dd/yyyy); if not, remove this line
SET "_month=%DATE:~-7,2%" & REM month goes second (dd/mm/yyyy); if not, remove this line
REM -- 4 digit year
SET "_year=%DATE:~-10,4%" & REM year goes first (yyyy/##/##); if not, remove this line
SET "_year=%DATE:~-4%" & REM year goes last (##/##/yyyy); if not, remove this line

REM -- The variables below are set to year-month-day without separators (yyyymmdd)
SET "today=%_year%%_month%%_day%" & REM today's date based on your selections above
SET "compareDate=20180727" & REM the date you are comparing with today

REM -- Here's where the magic happens with comparing the two dates
IF %compareDate% LSS %today% ECHO The comparison date is in the past.
IF %compareDate% EQU %today% ECHO The comparison date is today.
IF %compareDate% GTR %today% ECHO The comparison date is in the future.
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Without even an own code try the question is too broad. Hint when reversing the order to yyyy.mm.dd a simple string comparison with an [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `%DATE%` is that it returns the current date using the *short date format*, that is fully (endlessly) customizable. One user may configure its system to return `Fri053119`, and another user may choose `31/05/2019`, which is a complete nightmare for a BAT programmer.

One possible solution is to use **WMIC**, the command line interface to WMI. See wikipedia's [Windows Management Instrumentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation).

`wmic OS Get localdatetime` returns the date in a convenient format to directly parse it with a `FOR` command.

So, for example, you could,

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set wldt=%%a
set today=%wldt:~0,8%
```

to obtain the current date in a convenient format to use it for dates comparison

so you later can

```
if %today% gtr 20190101 (
  if %today% lss 20190630 (
    echo Yes!
  )
)
```

Comment: You shouldn't support double postings with double answers.

Comment: Well, you answered both and temporarily got rep before the other answer was deleted by moderators with the comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. If it is not a duplicate, tailor the post to the question and flag for undeletion.

Comment: A question on hold doesn't remove the answer, so there is no reason to post another answer, a comment referencing the other is the better way. OP notices it anyway.