# Windows batch compare fixed date with current date

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to compare a fixed date with current system date. I want to check if the current date is greater or same than fixed date. Example:

```
@ECHO OFF
set fixedDate=27-09-2018
set current=%date%

if %current% GEQ %fixedDate% (goto there)  else (goto here)

:here
echo "do nothing"

:there
echo "yes run it"
```

## Output:

```
"do nothing"
"yes run it"
```

Above code isn't working. Any suggestion in where I am doing mistake? Thanks in advance :)

## Edit:

I tried like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
set FixedDate=27-09-2018
set current=%date%

set "sdate1=%current:~-4%%current:~3,2%%current:~0,2%"
set "sdate2=%FixedDate:~-4%%FixedDate:~3,2%%FixedDate:~0,2%"

if %sdate1% GEQ %sdate2% (goto there)  else (goto here)

:here
echo "do nothing"

:there
echo "yes run it"
```

Didn't work either.

Output:

```
"yes run it"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare 2 dates in a Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649235/compare-2-dates-in-a-windows-batch-file)

Comment: Could also be duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670666/compare-2-dates-in-a-batch-file

Comment: @HackSlash I tried but didn't work for me.

Comment: How can the current date ever be greater than a future date?  Doesn't seem logically possible.

Comment: Your question doesn't require a batch file or any code because a future date by definition always has to be greater than the current date! Also @Jibon, if you try the code suggested in the comments, then please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51194469/edit) again to include it, along with a full explanation of what happened when you ran it.

Comment: @Compo, sorry for that. Actually it will be compare current date with a fixed date. If current date is greater than or same as the fixed date then one command will be run.

Comment: Of course it is going to run the `:there` label.  Batch files process their code line by line.  The only way to skip over lines is to use a `GOTO` like you did with your `IF` commands.

Comment: This code presumes that the `%DATE%` variable is in `dd-MM-yyyy` format. That might not be correct on another machine. Use `ECHO %DATE%` to see the current format.

Comment: @lit you are correct the output it `05-Jul-18`

Comment: @Jibon - That would suggest that your parsing of the current date is not correct. The format appears to be `dd-MMM-yyyy`.

Comment: @lit so, Do I need to change `fixedDate=07-Jul-18`? I mean same format as current date?

Comment: @Jibon, batch files know absolutely nothing about variable types which is pretty evident because most languages require you to declare the variables data type.  Everything is a character string in batch files. So you have to put the date into a YYYYMMDD format to determine if one is larger than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PowerShell which understands dates.

```
SET "REFDATE=2018-07-04"
FOR /F %%a IN ('powershell -NoProfile -Command "([Datetime]'%REFDATE%') -gt (Get-Date)"') DO (SET "COMPRESU=%%a")
ECHO %COMPRESU%

IF /I "%COMPRESU%" == "True" (GOTO DoTrue) ELSE (GOTO DoFalse)

:DoTrue
ECHO Doing TRUE
GOTO AfterDateTest

:DoFalse
ECHO Doing FALSE

:AfterDateTest
```

Alternatively, you could do the command in the if.

```
FOR /F %%a IN ('powershell -NoProfile -Command "([Datetime]'%REFDATE%') -gt (Get-Date)"') DO (SET "COMPRESU=%%a")
IF /I "%COMPRESU%" == "true" (truecmd.exe) ELSE (falsecmd.exe)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I would like to run a command. How can I do that? `if %COMPRESU% == "true"  (echo here)  else (echo there)`